# Which libraries for DS1302 real time clock and WS2811 LED strip do not conflict?

Tags: serial, rtc, led-strip

I am making a custom wall-clock, and need the Arduino (Uno or Nano) to connect to a DS1302 real time clock module and a WS2811 LED chain.

So I’m using [DS1302](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=5) for the clock, and [FastLED](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) for the lights. Individually these two libraries work fine, so I can either echo the time to the serial console, or I can drive the LEDs as I need.

But when I combine them there is some conflict happening and I get no LED output. The LED data goes over pin 6 and the clock uses pins 2,3,4 (these pins are customisable in code).

Even just adding a DS1302 initialisation to a working FastLED sketch causes no more LED output

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <DS1302.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 50
#define DATA_PIN 6

// Init the DS1302 - stops LEDs working
DS1302 rtc(2, 3, 4);

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() { 
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() { 
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS;i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
  }
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
}
```

What are my troubleshooting steps - should I try alternative libraries, or could I dig into the libraries themselves and see what hardware resources they might be using?

I guess as both the lights and the clock probably operate over a serial protocol, it could be a conflict with the serial drivers - maybe both using the same time-critical operations.

Edit: inserted sketch which demonstrates the issue

Comment: Don’t have access to actual code at the moment, the above hopefully is a minimum working example to demo the issue, also the light sequence is fairly complex and arbitrary, so at this stage just want to find any way of getting both rtc and leds operating at same time

Comment: Do you ever try to switch pin 3 to 9?

Comment: That DS1302 library you point to is very old. Did you try using a more recent library like the one from [Richard C. Miller](https://github.com/Makuna/Rtc/wiki) that can be installed from the Arduino IDE?

Comment: There are more precise RTC modules (DS3231) using I2C, which is supported by hardware: won't affect FastLED timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a library from within the IDE as StarCat suggested.

https://github.com/Makuna/Rtc

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <ThreeWire.h> 
#include <RtcDS1302.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 50
#define DATA_PIN 6

ThreeWire myWire(3,4,2); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() { 
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
   Rtc.Begin();
}

void loop() {
   RtcDateTime dt = Rtc.GetDateTime();

   for (int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS;i++) {
     leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
   }

FastLED.show();
delay(100);
}
```

I am able to get and use the time, and the LED output works.